# How to create multiple executable jars under same project, same src with sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have one project and project directory looks like this:

```
aProject/
    build.sbt
    project/Build.scala
    src/main/scala/
        packageA/MainA.scala
        packageB/MainB.scala
```

I want to package 2 fat jars, one containing packageA.MainA and the other containing packageB.MainB. How can I do this with sbt-assembly?